# Error in Document uploading

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, file-upload

I have a MVC application wherein there is a functionality where the user can upload documents. I am converting the document into byte[] and storing in db.I am getting a strange error for some cases(<5% cases). The document being uploaded is not clear. I am clueless as to how this can happen in very few cases.

The sample code which I am using is this .

```
public byte[] FileToByteArray(string fileName)
{
    byte[] fileData = null;

    using (FileStream fs = new File.OpenRead(fileName)) 
    { 
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length); 
        }
    }
    return fileData;
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You're going to need to describe the issue better than that. What do you mean "not clear"? What is the error?

Comment: You are using fs.Length.  You should be using binaryReader.Length.  The file stream is using encoding where the length is the number of characters.  Characters can be one or two bytes while the binary read is always one byte.